# Selecting fields with same name inside join

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I`ve got a sql query like this:

```
    SELECT com.*
from VE_COMMAND_SITE_BIND bnd INNER JOIN [dbo].[VE_COMMAND] com ON bnd.COMMAND_ID = com.ID
```

There is field named 'ON' in both tables. I want to select all the fields from the first table com as I do with com.*,
but the field 'ON' from the second table bnd. I also don`t want to mention all the com`s fields - I like com.*!

Is there any proper way in MSSQL to do such things?

Comment: Select what you need with proper aliases but   use `*` only for testing not for production

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "Can I select everything except one field from table com, and then one field from table bnd?" then the answer is "No. You have to define the result fields individually"

You can either do

```
 select com.*, bnd.[on] as bndon
```

or

```
 select com.field1, com.field2,...
```

Also, you should try to avoid calling your field "on" as `on` is a reserved word.

For maintainabilty and potential performance reasons, it is better practice to individually specify the fields you want to return from a `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wildcard * operator for your VE_Command ( com ) table and simply pick out the field you'd like from VE_COMMAND_SITE_BIND ( bnd ).

One thing to be aware of is naming clashes.  You say that in both tables, the field is called ON.  This may cause problems to any client application trying to access the field by name. ( which one does it pick, etc? )

Due to your requirement not to want to list all fields of com, probably easier to rename the one you're bringing out of bnd

```
SELECT 
   com.*,
   bnd.ON AS BindOn
FROM
   ...
```